# Auto Generated Folders inside Layout and other folders after installing PowerPivot for SharePoint 2010

Tags: powerpivot

We have installed PowerPivot for SharePoint in our Windows Server 2008 R2 and Configured its all services and everything works fine. But suddenly i found that there are many auto generated folders by Installation inside the Layout, Template and in other folders.
Does anyone know about this and are these folders required or these are unnecessary folders.[image: folders image]